# Using a JIRA workflow function to create a new issue in another project

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

**Context**

I have a JIRA project for core product which we use both for bug tracking and managing product backlog as epics and stories.
I have a number of projects using that core product - each has its own JIRA project. Each project may identify product bugs and/or new feature requests for the core product.

**Problem**

I have been looking at creating a workflow for the implementation projects which would include transitions to 'Product Fix Requested' and 'Product Feature Requested' steps.
I was planning to include workflow functions in those transitions that would create a new bug or improvement request in the core product project and link it to the issue in the implementation project.
This would allow us to keep track of project requests whilst keeping all the bugs a feature requests for the core product in one place.

**Question**

Does anyone know of any workflow plugins that provide this sort of functionality?
Alternatively, would anyone have any thoughts about how I might go about doing it myself. In particular, I'm not sure how I would get hold of the target project from within the function...?

Answer (score 3):

We've just achieved this by using the [CustomWare Jira Utilities](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/15453?versionId=41261) plugin.  Seems to work quite well in Jira 4.3 too.

Answer (score 1):

We use the [Jira Scripting Suite](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/16346) plugin. It allows you to do do pretty much anything via Jython scripts.

Using the Jira Code API can be a bit intimidating but [this example](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/JSS/Scripting+Samples?focusedCommentId=15990787#comment-15990787) should provide you a good start for creating issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is the [Create and Link plugin](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/JCLP/JIRA+Create+and+Link+Plugin). It allows you to clone an issue and move it to a different issue type, pre-populated with field values from the original issue. Whether it will create the issue in a different project is another matter. You may need to add a Groovy script move the clone.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to solve it with the ["Create and Link Issues"](https://codecentric.atlassian.net/wiki/display/WE/Post+Functions#PostFunctions-CreateAndLinkIssuesPostFunction) post function from [Workflow Essentials for JIRA](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/de.codecentric.jira.wes/server/overview).